# Spatial Join in ArcPy - one point shapefile to multiple polygon files

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I want to join a point file to many polygon files (i.e. different shapefiles) using a spatial join. Trying to do this in ArcPy via this script.  My thought was that the script would do a spatial join by iterating through a list of shapefiles to be joined. The idea: each iteration would need to take the previous spatial join output for an input to add new boundary info to the point file:

```
### Join polygons to points

#my target point file
target_features = output_files_dir + "\\" + "firestations_layer.shp"

#polygons I wish to join to the point file
aldermanic_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "aldermanic_boundary.shp"
census_block_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "census_block_boundary.shp"
census_blockgroup_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "census_blockgroup_boundary.shp"
census_tract_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "census_tract_boundary.shp"
county_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "county_boundary.shp"
municipal_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "municipal_boundary.shp"
school_dist_boundary = geog_boundary_files_dir + "\\" + "school_dist_boundary.shp"

out_feature_class = output_files_dir + "\\" + "spatialJoinTest.shp"

boundaryArray = [aldermanic_boundary, census_block_boundary, census_blockgroup_boundary, census_tract_boundary, county_boundary, municipal_boundary, school_dist_boundary]

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def spatialJoin():

    target_features = output_files_dir + "\\" + "firestations_layer.shp"
    out_feature_class = output_files_dir + "\\" + "spatialJoinTest.shp"

    
    for boundary in boundaryArray:
        #for the very first file, the output will be different from input
        if boundary == aldermanic_boundary:
            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, boundary, out_feature_class)
        else:
            #use the output of the last spatial join as input for new join
            #this will be used to iteratively add subsequent spatial joins to point file.
            target_features = out_feature_class
            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, boundary, out_feature_class)


spatialJoin()
```

However, this is giving me an error that the output feature class is the same as the input target features.  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: There are times where spatial join is appropriate, but this doesn't seem like one.  You really just want to process the join once, picking up the fields you need. An Intersect will do this.

Comment: Use `os.path.join` to build your paths. Instead of `target_features = output_files_dir + "\\" + "firestations_layer.shp"` , use `target_features = os.path.join( output_files_dir, "firestations_layer.shp")`

Comment: Thanks all.  BERA - will try your solution.   Vince, I'm familiar with intersect, but not sure how it would work in this case.  Can you elaborate?